# What is the meaning of the static field in AttemptController in following sample code ?

Tags: c#, oop, static

I am newbie in C# and trying to learn static keyword. I don't understand why we need to initialize static field twice. as my understanding static field preserve the value during the program execution.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        AttemptController Obj = new AttemptController(3, 2);
        Console.WriteLine("Maximum:   {0}", AttemptController.MaxAttempts);
        Console.WriteLine("Warning:   {0}", AttemptController.WarningAttempts);
        Console.WriteLine("Threshold: {0}", AttemptController.Threshold);

        AttemptController Obj1 = new AttemptController(7, 5);
        Console.WriteLine("Maximum:   {0}", AttemptController.MaxAttempts);
        Console.WriteLine("Warning:   {0}", AttemptController.WarningAttempts);
        Console.WriteLine("Threshold: {0}", AttemptController.Threshold);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    class AttemptController
    {
        internal static int MaxAttempts;
        internal static int WarningAttempts;
        internal static int Threshold;

        public AttemptController(int a, int b)
        {
            MaxAttempts = a;
            WarningAttempts = b;
            Threshold = MaxAttempts - WarningAttempts;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try making `AttemptController` class static

Comment: `AttemptController`?? Is this MVC app? if yes then having those static field is useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a couple of proposed changes:

- make the class static
- get rid of the constructor as static classes cannot have instance constructors.
- add a new method called `init` just for demo purposes.

  ```
  using System;

  namespace ConsoleApp4
  {
      internal class Program
      {
          private static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              AttemptController.Init(3, 2);
              Console.WriteLine("Maximum:   {0}", AttemptController.MaxAttempts);
              Console.WriteLine("Warning:   {0}", AttemptController.WarningAttempts);
              Console.WriteLine("Threshold: {0}", AttemptController.Threshold);

              AttemptController.Init(7, 5);
              Console.WriteLine("Maximum:   {0}", AttemptController.MaxAttempts);
              Console.WriteLine("Warning:   {0}", AttemptController.WarningAttempts);
              Console.WriteLine("Threshold: {0}", AttemptController.Threshold);
              Console.ReadLine();
      }
  }

      public static class AttemptController
      {
          internal static int MaxAttempts;
          internal static int WarningAttempts;
          internal static int Threshold;



          public static void Init(int a, int b)
          {
              MaxAttempts = MaxAttempts + a;
              WarningAttempts = WarningAttempts + b;
              Threshold = MaxAttempts - WarningAttempts;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Because you set `MaxAttempts`,`WarningAttempts`,`Threshold` fields in the constructor method.

When you use `AttemptController Obj = new AttemptController(3, 2);` it will set the value.

when you use will set `MaxAttempts = 3` and `WarningAttempts = 2`

```
AttemptController Obj = new AttemptController(3, 2);
```

when you use will set `MaxAttempts = 7` and `WarningAttempts = 5`

```
AttemptController Obj1 = new AttemptController(7, 5);
```

`static` fields let all instance use the same fields value.